# freely generating elements in an algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(\mathfrak{M}, \tau)$ be a W${}^{\ast}$-Algebra with (finite, normal, etc., whichever nice conditions one may find need for) tracial state. Elements $(a_{i})_{i\in I}\subset\mathfrak{M}$ shall be called **free**, exactly in case for all finite collections of polynomials $(p_{k})_{k<n}\subset\mathbb{C}[X]$ and indices $(i_{k})_{k<n}\subseteq I$ with $i_{j}\neq i_{k}$ for $j,k<n$ with $|j-k|=1$, it holds that:

$$.\forall{k<n}:\tau(p_{k}(a_{i_{k}}))=0.
~\Longrightarrow~.\tau(\prod_{k<n}p_{k}(a_{i_{k}}))=0.$$

**Question.** Let $(x_{i})_{i<N}\subset\mathfrak{M}$ be finitely many elements. Do there exist finitely many free elements $(a_{j})_{j<M}\subset\mathfrak{M}$, so that the $x_{i}$ are somehow (*e. g.* spectral-theoretically) generated by the $a_{j}$?

---

**Remark 1.** of course a desirable consquence, is that the free elements are somehow (*e. g.* spectral-theoretically) constructable out of the original elements.

**Remark 2.** It is not necessary that $M=N$ or that even $M\leq N$. An answer for the case $N=2$ would also be useful. One can also always reduce to the case, that all original elements are self-adjoint (resp. positive, resp. unitary).

**Remark 3.** This question of mine essentially asks, if there be a **non-commutative Gram-Schmidt process**.

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be $\mathfrak M$?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: I had to strike the word „algebraically“, as it may then be trivially false: consider a single self-adjoint element $a$ with non-discrete spektrum. Work in the W${}^{\ast}$-Algebra $\{a\}’'$. Let $f:\sigma(a)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-zero continuous function with countably infinitely many zeroes — thus $f\neq p$ and hence $f(a)\neq p(a)$ for all polynomials $p\in\mathbb{C}[X]$. Consider $x_{0}=a$ and $x_{1}=f(a)$. It seems, it may be impossible to generate these elements *algebraically* by free elements.